# Input dynamic constants assignment

Tags: ruby, string, input

Can I try with another method or rewrite my code? I try again many time.
I gave up.

```
def Input
    puts("What day?")
    Date = gets.chomp
    puts("What month")
    Month = gets.chomp
    puts("What year?")
    Year = gets.chomp
    puts("Input your event?")
    Event = gets.chomp
    text = file.open("Event.txt")
    return[Date, Month, Year, Event]
end
Input
```

Comment: There’s no reason to use constants here, just use `date`, `month`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [highline](https://github.com/JEG2/highline) .

Use `highline/import`

so the way it will work is

```
require "highline/import"

def input
    arr = []
    date = ask('What day? ')
    month = ask('What Month?')
    year = ask('What Year? ')
    event = ask('What Event?')
    [data, month, year ,event]
end

input
```

Comment: /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- highline/import (LoadError)
 from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
 from DateTime.rb:3:in `<main>'

Comment: Do u have highline installed?